# Седьмая вода на киселе

Tags: фразеология

Всех с наступающим!!
Об очень дальнем родстве говорят "седьмая вода на киселе". А откуда вообще такое выражение? Почему вода и почему седьмая? И почему,собственно, на киселе?

Answer (score 5):

Вот такие версии нашла на "Грамоте".

1. Это выражение связано с изготовлением киселя на Руси. Седьмой водой называли воду, появившуюся на длительно стоявшем киселе седьмой раз, отчего ее вкус ничего общего с киселем не имел.

2.Это выражение собственно русское. Картофельная мука (крахмал), которую используют для приготовления киселя, получается из растертого картофеля путем промывания его водой. После отстаивания крахмал оседает. При нескольких повторных промываниях (в семи водах) осадка практически уже не бывает.

3.Это выражение происходит из старинного способа приготовления киселя, когда необмолоченное овсяное зерно замачивалось в горячей воде. Первая вода вымывала большую часть крахмала и была наиболее густой (собственно киселем). Вторая - жиже. Третья - еще жиже. Седьмая вода была уже практически не киселем, а именно водой.

Comment: Версии малоотличимы друг от друга. 
Про картофель впрочем - сомнительно.
Кисели на Руси были именно овсяными, а картошка стала повсеместной культурой в XVIII-XIX веке.